# 'Option not supported' error when using SQL Server with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to retrieve data from both MySQL and SQL Server on the same console application. I manage to retrieve data from MySQL, however when I trying to retrieve data from SQL Server, I got `System.ArgumentException: 'Option not supported. Parameter name: multipleactiveresultsets'` error.

The following is my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLDb" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=sakila;uid=some_user;password=some_password"/>
    <add name="SQLDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And my C#:

```cs
#region MySQL.
{
    var dbContext = new MySQLDb();
    var dbSet = dbContext.Set<Actor>();

    var actors = dbSet.ToList();
}
#endregion

#region SQLServer.
{
    var dbContext = new SQLDb();
    var dbSet = dbContext.Set<User>();

    var users = dbSet.ToList(); // <-- Throw exception.
}
#endregion
```

If I disable `entityFramework` section in `app.config` and MySQL code block in my C# code, I can retrieve data from SQL Server without any issue.

Version info

- MySQL.Data.Entity 6.10.8
- NET Framework 4.6.1

Any idea?

---

**Update 1**

Found out that the connection type for `MySQLDb` is `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection`, so that works just fine. But when instantiating `SQLDb`, the connection type is still `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`. How should we fix this?

Comment: Remove the option in question from the connection string?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I removed `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`, the error changed to saying `App=EntityFramework` is not supported. Removing both ends up with `System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: 'The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.'
` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that we are using `MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration` (in the `app.config`) which set the default connection factory to use `MySqlConnectionFactory`.

The solution is to use a custom `DbConfiguration` in place of `MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration` to deter from setting the default connection factory.

```cs
public class MySQLDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MySQLDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices(MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, new MySqlProviderServices());
        SetProviderFactory(MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, new MySqlClientFactory());
    }
}
```

Declare the instance as readonly somewhere in the code,

```cs
private static readonly MySQLDbConfiguration DBConfig = new MySQLDbConfiguration();
```

and set the configuration **PRIOR TO using any EF features**

```cs
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(DBConfig);
```

And our `app.config` now becomes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLDb" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=sakila;uid=some_user;password=some_password"/>
    <add name="SQLDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

If you're opt to use `app.config` instead of deriving a custom `DbConfiguration`, you can do the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <!-- Alternative to custom DbConfiguration. -->
  <configSections>
    <section name = "entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLDb" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=sakila;uid=some_user;password=some_password"/>
    <add name="SQLDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp net 5.0, install the Nuget found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), but first uninstall Mysql.data.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be of any help to anybody, but in **my** situation, it turned out that when I copied in the "connection string" **I accidentally left out the "Server=" part.**

I had "HOSTNAME; User Id=USER; etc.".
It is supposed to be, **"Server=** HOSTNAME; etc."

Obvious in hindsight.

It's an easy mistake to make, since we're using AWS RDS and the host name is incredibly long, like 60 characters of gobbledegook, so you have to be extra careful copying it around. Essentially, the error reporting was trying to tell me that "HOST;" by itself is not a "supported option" but "Server=HOST;" *is* supported. It's too bad the message isn't more clear, might have saved me some hearburn.

**Basically, if you get this error, first double-check your connection string** to make sure it has all the correct options in the correct syntax, which may be different for the version you have. If that's your issue, it's the easiest to fix.